# Origin of a segmentation fault with a code snippet

Tags: c, for-loop, segmentation-fault, gdb

I used an original code snippet with which I did tests. The original form was the following below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

 int i,j;
 int  size_x = 100;
 int  size_y = 100;
 int  size_z = 100;

 double ***x;

 x = malloc(size_y * sizeof(*x));
 for (i = 0; i < size_y; i++)
    x[i] = malloc(size_x * sizeof(**x));

 for (j = 0; j < size_x; j++)
    x[i][j] = malloc(size_z * sizeof(***x));

 return 0;

}
```

At the execution, I get a `Segmentation error` and I don't where this error could come from.

What is the cause of this error? `i` index is equal to `size_y-1` after the first loop, the second loop seems to be correct...

`gdb` gives with `backtrace`:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004005b6 in main () at main_Syntax_Alloc_SEGFAULT.c:17
17      x[i][j] = malloc(size_z * sizeof(***x));
```

Since, I have rectified this code snippet to have a correct allocation, by doing :

```
double ***x;
x = malloc(size_y * sizeof(*x));
for (i = 0; i < size_y; i++)
 {
  x[i] = malloc(size_x * sizeof(**x));
  for (j = 0; j < size_x; j++)
     x[i][j] = malloc(size_z * sizeof(***x));
 }
```

But I want to know the origin of segmentation error for the first version of snippet above.

Comment: `x[i][j] = malloc(size_z * sizeof(***x));` Ask this: what is the value of `i` on that line?

Comment: on that line, `i` is equal to `size_y-1`, isn't it ?

Comment: Previous `for` ends when `i < size_y` is `false`..... so ......`i=???`

Comment: ok, `i=100` at the end of first loop

Comment: so... you are accessing your `malloc`ated memory out of bounds..... indexes must be `0` to `99`

Comment: thanks and sorry for this error of beginner

Comment: Don't be a three star programmer.... http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: -@LPs 51 that's what I have seen since ì=100`for the second loop, regards

Answer (score 0):

> `i` index is equal to `size_y-1` after the first loop

No, it isn't. If it were the loop hadn't ended.

After the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < size_y; i++)
```

the value of `i` is not `<size_y`. And with this, this line

```
x[i][j] =  ...
```

accesses invalid memory, invoking undefined behaviour. Anything might happen from then on.

A simple `printf()` of `i` after the loop would prove this.

---

BTW, all those `int`s should be `size_t`s.